# How to get current Content from HTML Table with PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to edit data by using HTML and PHP. In my HTML file there is a table that contains the data from a SQLite database (SELECT statement works fine). The PHP file contains the UPDATE statement with some concat.

**sshTunnel.sqlite --> mydata**

```
CREATE TABLE "mydata" ("ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "SSH_USER" VARCHAR, "SSH_IP" VARCHAR, "SSH_PORT" VARCHAR, "SSH_PW" VARCHAR, "SSH_KEYFILE" VARCHAR, "TUNNEL_LOCAL_INTERFACE" VARCHAR, "TUNNEL_LOCAL_PORT" VARCHAR, "TUNNEL_REMOTE_IP" VARCHAR, "TUNNEL_REMOTE_PORT" VARCHAR, "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR)
```

**This is the "HTML" part:**

```
while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
    $output .= '<tr>
                    <td class="ID" data-id1="' . $row['ID'] . '">' . $row['ID'] . '</td>
                    <td class="SSH_USER" data-id2="' . $row['ID'] . '" contenteditable="true">' . $row['SSH_USER'] . '</td>
                    <td class="SSH_IP" data-id3="' . $row['ID'] . '" contenteditable="true">' . $row['SSH_IP'] . '</td>
                    <td class="SSH_PORT" data-id4="' . $row['ID'] . '" contenteditable="true">' . $row['SSH_PORT'] . '</td>
                    <td class="SSH_PW" data-id5="' . $row['ID'] . '" contenteditable="true">' . $row['SSH_PW'] . '</td>
                    <td class="SSH_KEYFILE" data-id6="' . $row['ID'] . '" contenteditable="true">' . $row['SSH_KEYFILE'] . '</td>
                    <td class="TUNNEL_LOCAL_INTERFACE" data-id7="' . $row['ID'] . '" contenteditable="true">' . $row['TUNNEL_LOCAL_INTERFACE'] . '</td>
                    <td class="TUNNEL_LOCAL_PORT" data-id8="' . $row['ID'] . '" contenteditable="true">' . $row['TUNNEL_LOCAL_PORT'] . '</td>
                    <td class="TUNNEL_REMOTE_IP" data-id9="' . $row['ID'] . '" contenteditable="true">' . $row['TUNNEL_REMOTE_IP'] . '</td>
                    <td class="TUNNEL_REMOTE_PORT" data-id10="' . $row['ID'] . '" contenteditable="true">' . $row['TUNNEL_REMOTE_PORT'] . '</td>
                    <td class="DESCRIPTION" data-id11="' . $row['ID'] . '" contenteditable="true">' . $row['DESCRIPTION'] . '</td>
                    <td><button type="button" name="btn_edit" data-id12="' . $row['ID'] . '" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-block btn_edit">Editieren</button></td>
                    <td><button type="button" name="btn_delete" data-id13="' . $row['ID'] . '" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-block btn_delete">Löschen</button></td>
                </tr>';
}
```

**This is the script part:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_edit', function()
{
    var ID = $(this).data("id12");          
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to edit this?"))
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "edit.php",
            data: {ID:ID},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert('ajax success');
                fetch_data();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Finally, this is the PHP part:**

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('sshTunnel.sqlite');
$db->exec('UPDATE mydata SET    SSH_USER="' . $_POST['SSH_USER'] . '", 
                                SSH_IP="' . $_POST['SSH_IP'] . '",  
                                SSH_PORT="' . $_POST['SSH_PORT'] . '", 
                                SSH_PW="' . $_POST['SSH_PW'] . '", 
                                SSH_KEYFILE="' . $_POST['SSH_KEYFILE'] . '", 
                                TUNNEL_LOCAL_INTERFACE="' . $_POST['TUNNEL_LOCAL_INTERFACE'] . '", 
                                TUNNEL_LOCAL_PORT="' . $_POST['TUNNEL_LOCAL_PORT'] . '", 
                                TUNNEL_REMOTE_IP="' . $_POST['TUNNEL_REMOTE_IP'] . '", 
                                TUNNEL_REMOTE_PORT="' . $_POST['TUNNEL_REMOTE_PORT'] . '", 
                                DESCRIPTION="' . $_POST['DESCRIPTION'] . '" 
                                WHERE ID="' . $_POST['ID'] . '"');
$db->close();
?>
```

It seems, that there is no content buffered. Instead of updating the database correctly, the scripts "delete" all the row content. It seems, that they update all columns with **NULL**. Does anyone know why?

Comment: It seems like $_POST is not getting data in your php page . Try to print $_POST .I am sure you will get null array .

Comment: Correct. So how do I fix that problem? I tried $_GET, but this does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax call you set `data: {ID: ID}` that is all which will be send. Only $_POST['ID'] will be set.

You have to send the data of the elements.

For you current HTML Code it could be the following code.

```
var ID = $(this).data("id12");
var data = {ID: ID};
$(this).closest('tr').find('td[class]').each(function() {
    data[$(this).attr('class')] = $(this).text();
});
console.log(data); //check if the data you send is complete
```

Then use `data: data` in the ajax call to send the data.

But you should change the structure of you HTML. Use a data-name or something similar to set the name not a class.

Comment: Perfect! This is the solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "edit.php",
        data: {ID:ID},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert('ajax success');
            fetch_data();
        }
    });
```

here you're only sending ID as post data...that's why in your php script other post values are null. So either all post values rewriting `data: {ID:ID, SSH_USER: SSH_USER,....}` OR read this SSH_USER value from some kind of config file.